# Prevent glassfish standalone client from asking for a firewall exception

Tags: java, ejb, glassfish-3, windows-firewall

**Context** : We are developping a EJB 3 stand alone application on Glassfish v3.1.2.2 .

**Problem** : When connecting from a Windows workstation to Glassfish, the end user is prompted with the Windows "add firewall rule dialog".

This is unacceptable behavior to us. This application will be deployed on thousands of workstations and our end-users may or may not have administrative rights and may or may not understand the dialog.

**Setup** :

We used the Oracle Glassfish 3.1 documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gkusn.html#scrolltoc) to run the client application in stand-alone mode. Specifically, we copied the files under **as-install**/*modules* to the client, and added **gf-client.jar** to the classpath. Everything works fine as you can see from the screenshot below.

**Thoughts** :

- The client application should not need to open a ServerSocket (I think this is what triggers the dialog)
- In fact, the client application does not use the ServerSocket (as seen in the short, selft-contained example I posted below)
- The opened ServerSocket port differs every time. I checked this by matching the process' `PID` and the output of `netstat -ano` which looks something like this :

`tasklist.exe :`

```
    Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
    ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
    java.exe                    118692 Console                    7     88.736 K
```

`netstat -ano :`

```
    Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
    TCP    0.0.0.0:52641          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       118692
```

It seems odd to me this port would change every time : note that there used to be a bug in netstat, but it should not apply to Windows 7 ( see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331078) ) In any case, the dialog poppup appears, which I think means something wants to **LISTEN** on the client.

The EJB module is available on github [here](https://github.com/charlesvg/so-ssce-gf3-firewall-prompt-ejb) , the client application is available [here](https://github.com/charlesvg/so-ssce-gf3-firewall-prompt-ca)

[add-firewall-exception-popup http://belgian-united-gaming.be/obasi-ssce-gf.png](http://belgian-united-gaming.be/obasi-ssce-gf.png)

Please advise & thank you for your help.